# Redirect AWS sdks' default endpoint to mocked localstack endpoints

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hosts, dnsmasq, localstack

I have multiple Java spring boot services (around 20 of them) using Amazon SDKs for S3, SQS, DynamoDB, etc..

Currently, to use Amazon Web Service I only need to specify my AWS key & secret.

```
ACCESS_AWS_KEY=<MY_KEY>
ACCESS_AWS_SECRET=<MY_SECRET>
```

However, I wanted to setup offline dev enviroment so I started to dockerize my services and set up a single multi-docker container with all my services dockerized and [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) should be used instead of remote AWS service to allow complete offline development.

docker-compose.yml looks something like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  service_1:
    build: ./repos/service_1
    links:
    - service_2:
    - localstack
  service_2:
    build: ./repos/service_2
    links:
    - localstack
  service_3:
    build: ./repos/service_3
    links:
    - localstack
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
```

Amazon SDK provides AWS_REGION env variable, but not an endpoint environment variable which I can easily use in all services.

I also don't want to make code changes in my services to accommodate the new  non-default endpoint.

I want a generic solution to forward requests like this:

```
dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com => localstack_1:4569
s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com => localstack_1:4572
```

where **localstack_1** is a linked docker container of localstack and reachable by other containers.

I came across [extra_hosts:](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) in docker-compose, but it only redirects to IPs and has no hostname resolving.

Also, notice that I have dozens of ports exposed in localstack from 4569 to 4582.

I thought about running a script on each machine setting up a vhost in some way, or forwarding all outgoing connections from all containers to a centralized request forwarder service, but have no clue where to start.

This will only used as a offline dev environment and will not receive any real traffic.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I've got docker containers for several services using moto (which localstack is based on) and I have to specify endpoint URL's for each of them.  I ended up using `direnv` and setting environment variables to the URL to mock_*:5000, so for example sqs would be http://mock_sqs:5000.  Since I do my testing on other containers and the ports are exposed, I don't really need to map the ports to my local host, although I do anyway.

Comment: Did you find a solution, because it looks like I'm in the same trap? :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: See my solution below :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was able to finally find a solution for this. I had to actually go through localstack code base to be able to find the solution. 
Couple of quick things :

- Localstack is not integrated with IAM. So it just simply ignores the secret key or password.
- If you're using IAM, you now need to have a flag to override the endpoint. You can probably have a flag to indicate localstack mode.

Couple of classes which I found helpful if you're debugging issues :
https://github.com/atlassian/localstack/blob/master/localstack/ext/java/src/test/java/com/atlassian/localstack/SQSMessagingTest.java 
https://github.com/atlassian/localstack/blob/master/localstack/ext/java/src/test/java/com/atlassian/localstack/TestUtils.java

Now for the solution :

```
AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4576/", awsRegion.getName());
    AmazonSQSClient client =  (AmazonSQSClient) AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(configuration.getSqsConfiguration().getCredentialsProvider())
        .withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint)
        .build();
```

Here http://localhost:4576/ is where localstacks runs SQS. Don't miss the trailing slash. 
For using this in camel route is same as using AWS resources. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: But, you still modified the code, assume the code is Golang, python, you need to modify it everywhere.


At the begging, we plan to use localstack for our CI test. 
but It turns out we need to modify our code ....

Comment: other option would be proxy which redirect aws calls to localstack.